# Unity Photon Handle Match Data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, spawning

I'm building a multiplayer game that has instanced battles (find match matchmaking). I have the matchmaking finished and it throws the 6 (3v3) players into an empty room using 
 `PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel('Game');` 
This shows 6 empty rooms. 
 **What I need:** I need help spawning the players while also keeping the game data for each particular match organized in some way (file, scriptable object, etc). This is useful for the matches themselves as well as stuff like match history later on. 
I would appreciate any help. Thanks